# Como pegar valor da combobox no Angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma combobox na minha view e quero pegar o valor dela e imprimir na tela em outro lugar, estou conseguindo imprimir apenas o index do item selecionado, será que alguém pode me ajudar?

**HTML:**

```
                                       <div  class="form-group">
                                            <label>Departamento</label>
                                            <span style="color: red;">*</span>
                                            <select ng-model="orientador.value"
                                                    class="form-control"
                                                    ng-required="true">
                                                <option value="">Selecione o departamento:</option>
                                                <option ng-repeat="option in lista_departamento.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                       {{orientador.value}}
```

**JS:**

```
 $scope.lista_departamento = {
        availableOptions: [],
        model: null
    };

  //---------------------------------------get Lista Departamneto

    var getListaDepartamento = function () {
        $http.get("get_departamento").then(function (resposta) {
            var departamento = [];
            for (var i in resposta.data){
                departamento.push({id: resposta.data[i].cod_departamento, name: resposta.data[i].nome});
            }
            $scope.lista_departamento.availableOptions = departamento;
        });
    };

    getListaDepartamento();
```

**RESULTADO:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava definindo o value como sendo meu id, reutilizei um código meu que precisava disso e acabei esquecendo de alterar:

**como estava:**

```
   <option ng-repeat="option in lista_departamento.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
```

**como era pra ser:**

```
   <option ng-repeat="option in lista_departamento.availableOptions" value="{{option.name}}">{{option.name}}</option>
```